# What was Gustavo (Gus) Fring's back story?

Tags: breaking-bad

Hank and the DEA managed to find documents to show that Gus was from Chile, spent some years in Mexico, then moved to the US. However it seems that we are never really told what Gus's back story was---or perhaps I simply missed it.

It seems to me that he is obviously not from Chile, because he speaks Castellano/Spanish with a heavy American accent. (But correct me if I'm wrong about what sounds to me like a heavy American accent---I am not an expert in the Spanish language.)

So, what is his actual back story? Where is he actually from? (It is possible that this question is not answerable, but perhaps there were some clues that I missed.)

Comment: There's nothing anyone can tell you that will be as detailed as the [Breaking Bad Wiki page on him](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Gustavo_Fring). I'm not sure where/how they attained all the information (some of it may be made up), but much of it was divulged on various episodes of the show.

Comment: Yea, I saw that site. Seems like a bunch of fan speculation. Somewhere on that site it was even speculated that Gus was an illegitimate son of Pinochet which is just absurd.

Comment: Well, there's plenty of facts there, supported by episode citations.  Whatever is made up is minimal, and wasn't on the show.

Comment: Might In "Better Call Saul" we might get some refrences.

Comment: The show's not going to let his accent get in the way of the plot.

Answer (score 3):

> So, what is his actual back story? Where is he actually from? (It is possible that this question is not answerable, but perhaps there were some clues that I missed.)

For the most part, **it's unanswerable**. It's intentionally left a mystery on-screen. Honestly, anything they could have put in the show as his backstory would fail to have as much as an impact as not saying anything. It also hasn't been mentioned or expanded on in any interview with his Actor Giancarlo Esposito, or creator Vince Gilligan. [In fact he publicly stated that he doesn't know](http://www.avclub.com/article/vince-gilligan-walks-us-through-season-four-of-ibr-63013):

> All through episode eight, Gus Fring is not wanting people to know about his background. He apparently has some backstory that’s deep and dark and allows him to avoid getting killed at the end of episode eight, but we’re wondering this whole time, “Who is this guy? Who was he in Chile? What is he trying to hide?” **To be honest, we haven’t quite nailed that down. It has something to do with the Pinochet government, we think, but that’s about as close as we’ve gotten. At the end of the day, try not to nail down anything that we don’t have to.**

"We" of course referring to the creative staff.

Answer (score -2):

He is Au**GUS**to Pinocet's son, a generalissimo who committed atrocities under his father's regime.

Comment: You might want to elaborate that answer a little more with some more backing for your theory.